# Get page ID outside the loop, matching menu ID

Tags: customization, themes

How can I get the ID of the current post/page/category in a way that matches the ID I get from menus using `get_post_meta( $item->ID )['_menu_item_object_id'][0]`? I intend to use it in a JavaScript function.

- For pages, including the Posts Page, it is the page ID
- For categories, it is the category ID

I have tried using `global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->post->ID;`, but it gives the ID of a post for category pages and the Posts Page. (first or last displayed post, depending on whether it is before or after the loop)

More info:

I add the last modified date and ID to menu items as data attributes from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267864/get-last-modified-date-for-menu-link) and want to save the last visit date to localstorage, keyed with the ID from the menu so I can compare them.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What are you trying to do exactly? Give us an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to get the ID regardless of what type of object it is- term, post, page.

There is also the [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) function, which will give you more details, but will have some structural differences depending on object type.

Comment: `get_queried_object_id()` still returns the first post for the Posts Page, so I ended up using `get_queried_object()->ID`, falling back to `get_queried_object()->cat_ID` or `get_queried_object_id()`

Answer (score -1):

This should do it...

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```